# Commuting matrices with a transpose conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dagger-categories

Two matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable iff they commute. 
Can anything be said about the simultaneous diagonalizability if two matrices commute but with a dagger? This happens when both A and B are Hermitian.

That is, 
$AB = (BA)^\dagger$

Comment: Title: Careful, the matrices $A$,$B$ need not commute.

Comment: Note that this occurs for arbitrary Hermitian $A,B$, but in this case the matrices $A,B$ need not be *simultaneously* diagonalizable.

Comment: Two **diagonalizable** matrices that commute are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, they must commute.  So if in addition $AB = (BA)^\dagger$, we have $(BA)^\dagger = BA$, i.e. their product is Hermitian.  Now $A$ and $B$ commute with $BA$.  Thus the eigenspaces of $BA$ are invariant under both $A$ and $B$.  There are two cases:

1. On an eigenspace $V = V_\lambda$ of $BA$ for a nonzero $\lambda$, we have $AB = \lambda I$, so 
   $B|_V = \lambda (A|_V)^{-1}$.
2. On the null space $V = \ker(BA)$ of $BA$, we have $BA = 0$.  Thus $AV \subseteq \ker(B)$ and $BV \subseteq \ker(A)$.